# Adding remote method to build-in User model not working in Loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I am very new to loopback. I am trying to add a new remote method to build-in User model by following this [link](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Adding-remote-methods-to-built-in-models.html#additional-considerations).But i am getting the below error while trying to access the API.

> {"error":{"statusCode":401,"name":"Error","message":"Authorization
>   Required"}}

But as per the above link, API can be access by all the users of the application since we are configuring ACL for users in such a way. What am i doing wrong?

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Put your code to enable the others to help

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not add the ACL entry for the new remote method in [the User's model configuration.](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/master/common/models/user.json#L25-L86)

You need to add an entry with the `EXECUTE` access type, similar to

```
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$everyone",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "myNewRemoteMethod",
  "accessType": "EXECUTE"
}
```